# Html report configuration for Jmeter Test

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, kibana, easyhtmlreport, html-reports-jenkins

i have a requirement is need to provide the HTML report for the Jmeter Test.
We are able to configured the Dashboard report [http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html],But in that report we are not able to get the 90% response time.

So other than **Dashboard report**, **JmeterANT** any other Html Report is available to configure.

If any one know about Kibana Dashboard for HTML Report, let me know for configuration.

Comment: Any one can tell me about how to start the influx DB.Here is the http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/ document i am refer to configure.But unable to the start the server.

May i know where is need to start the server and how to execute the below commands 'influxd -config /path/to/config/file' as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually looking into [your link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general) I can see the following:

> Percentiles used by Summary table and Percentile graphs can be adjusted to different values by using the 3 properties:
>
> - aggregate_rpt_pct1 : Defaults to 90
> - aggregate_rpt_pct2 : Defaults to 95
> - aggregate_rpt_pct3 : Defaults to 99

So you should be able to see at least 3 above or amend the values according to your needs.

---

Apart from listed I'm aware of 2 more approaches:

1. You can configure a [Grafana Dashboard](https://grafana.net/dashboards/1152) like below:

   [image: JMeter Grafana Dashboard]

   and feed it data from JMeter using [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener).
2. You can use a 3rd-party analysis service like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) which can report a lot of centiles including 90%

   [image: Blazemeter Sense Percentiles Composite Timeline]

Comment: Dmitry Could please tell me the configuration part for the Grafana Dashboard? And I think BM.Sense is the commercial tool, But my client looking for the open source tool any other open source tool is available for HTML Report?

Comment: BM.Sense is [free up to certain extent](https://sense.blazemeter.com/pricing/). With regards to Grafana - don't expect anyone will be doing your job, you have direction, you have documentation - go ahead.

Comment: Any one can tell me about how to start the influx DB.Here is the http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/ document i am refer to configure.But unable to the start the server.

May i know where is need to start the server and how to execute the below commands 'influxd -config /path/to/config/file' as well.